# Any method to count Windows click count (C#)?

Tags: c#, windows, count, click

I'm trying to write a simple app that counts every mouse click that occurs in Windows (left and right separated), not only within a form. So far i did not have any success in finding such solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the [Win32 Hook API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959(v=vs.85).aspx) to capture mouse events. Stephen Toub provides a nice bit of sample code on his [MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589468.aspx) about setting up a mouse hook.

```
class InterceptMouse
{
    private static LowLevelMouseProc _proc = HookCallback;
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

    public static void Main()
    {
        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
        Application.Run();
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
    }

    private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelMouseProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc,
                GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 &&
            MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)
        {
            MSLLHOOKSTRUCT hookStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));
            Console.WriteLine(hookStruct.pt.x + ", " + hookStruct.pt.y);
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

    private enum MouseMessages
    {
        WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
        WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
        WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
        WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
        WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
        WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct POINT
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
    {
        public POINT pt;
        public uint mouseData;
        public uint flags;
        public uint time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
        LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
        IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
}
```

In your code you would set this up to record `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` events.